# Plinq gives different results from Linq - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

Can anyone tell me what the correct Plinq code is for this? I'm adding up the square root of the absolute value of the sine of each element fo a double array, but the Plinq is giving me the wrong result.

Output from this program is:

Linq aggregate = 75.8310477905274  (correct)
Plinq aggregate = 38.0263653589291 (about half what it should be)

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't work out what...

(I'm running this with Visual Studio 2008 on a Core 2 Duo Windows 7 x64 PC.)

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double[] array = new double[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            {
                array[i] = i;
            }

            double sum1 = array.Aggregate((total, current) => total + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Math.Sin(current))));
            Console.WriteLine("Linq aggregate = " + sum1);

            IParallelEnumerable<double> parray = array.AsParallel<double>();
            double sum2 = parray.Aggregate((total, current) => total + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Math.Sin(current))));
            Console.WriteLine("Plinq aggregate = " + sum2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate works slightly differently in PLINQ.

From [MSDN Blogs:](http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam/archive/2008/06/05/8576194.aspx)

> Rather than expecting a value to
> initialize the accumulator to, the
> user gives us a factory function that
> generates the value:

```
public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    return source.AsParallel().Aggregate(
        () => new double[2],
        (acc, elem) => { acc[0] += elem; acc[1]++; return acc; },
        (acc1, acc2) => { acc1[0] += acc2[0]; acc1[1] += acc2[1]; return acc1; },
        acc => acc[0] / acc[1]);
}
```

> Now, PLINQ can initialize an
> independent accumulator for each
> thread. Now that each thread gets its
> own accumulator, both the folding
> function and the accumulator combining
> function are free to mutate the
> accumulators. PLINQ guarantees that
> accumulators will not be accessed
> concurrently from multiple threads .

So, in your case, you would also need to pass an accumulator function which sums the outputs of the paralleled aggregates (hence why you're seeing a result that is roughly half of what it should be).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you MSDN Blogs. It now seems to be working correctly. I changed my code as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Test();
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            double[] array = new double[100];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; ++i)
            {
                array[i] = i;
            }

            double sum1 = array.Aggregate((total, current) => total + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Math.Sin(current))));
            Console.WriteLine("Linq aggregate = " + sum1);

            IParallelEnumerable<double> parray = array.AsParallel();

            double sum2 = parray.Aggregate
            (
                0.0,
                (total1, current1) => total1 + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(Math.Sin(current1))),
                (total2, current2) => total2 + current2,
                acc => acc
            );

            Console.WriteLine("Plinq aggregate = " + sum2);
        }
    }
}
```